# how do we write a C++ function checkParens that takes as input

Tags: c++

Using a stack instead of a counter, how do we write a C++ function checkParens that takes as input a
string representing some expression with parentheses and returns the boolean true if the
parentheses match and false otherwise

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a free code-writing service. Show us what you've tried yourself.

Comment: what you did try and how we can help you?

Comment: i wrote down what i would essentially do, more like an example will share my line of thought asap

Comment: take, checkParens ( "((a + b) * (c + d) - 7)*8")
would return true, while
checkParens("(a + b) * c)") would return false

Comment: the problem i have is that i don't have much experience using stacks, been trying to read up on them. I just started coding in C++

Comment: So let's see your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

1) Declare a character stack S.

2) Now traverse the expression string exp.

a) If the current character is a starting bracket (‘(‘ or ‘{‘ or ‘[‘) then push it to stack.

b) If the current character is a closing bracket (‘)’ or ‘}’ or ‘]’) then pop from stack and if the popped character is the matching starting bracket then fine else parenthesis are not balanced.

3) After complete traversal, if there is some starting bracket left in stack then “not balanced”

Time Complexity: O(n)

Auxiliary Space: O(n) for stack.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/